# ProjectCollection equivalent for Clickonce

Tags: clickonce, build-automation

Microsoft created [ProjectCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.evaluation.projectcollection.aspx) ([BuildEngine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.buildengine.engine.aspx) on frameworks below 4) to use MSBuild directly on code.

Is there any equivalent to publish applications through clickonce or do we have to call Mage.exe by command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, you can use msbuild to build and publish the apps; mage is used to create the manifests required by ClickOnce. There is no change to this with .NET 4.

Comment: I was trying to avoid using Process (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx). But I ended using it to call mage to generate and sign the manifests.